# What are the possible drops for defeating Yeti Zombie?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

A Yeti Zombie spawned in Ancient Egypt for me just now, and the game says I should try to defeat it in order to obtain fabulous treasure. I killed it in the game and got a lunch box, containing just one normal key (useful for unlocking). I don't think the prize is THAT awesome. Is that all?

What are the other possibilities for Yeti Zombie drops?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128263/what-causes-a-treasure-yeti-to-run-away

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Killing Yetis can drop multiple lunchboxes.

Each lunchbox can contain either keys or diamonds.

http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Yeti

Comment: I see. It's only diamonds or keys, not that exciting.

Comment: @user1032613 Yeti in Egypt dropping Diamonds.... It sure **sounds** exciting :)

Comment: you said multiple lunchboxes, so its possible to get more than 1 per yeti?

Comment: @spartacus Yes, the trivia section of my link has *In the "You got a Present!" Notification, there is a button called "open all". This is because you can get more than 1 lunch box when you kill a Treasure Yeti.* there is also a image that shows a 2 lb drop.

Answer (score 1):

The lunchboxes always contain 1000 coins.

Since gate keys are no longer in the game, and diamonds have been repurposed as a premium currency, this is currently the only thing you get from Yetis.