# What causes a treasure Yeti to run away?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I was on a level against a treasure Yeti.  I don't remember having this problem previously but it could simply be due to the plants I was using.  In this case, I was using the short range snapdragon plants so I was not covering the right most columns.  I wasn't paying full attention, but by the time I saw the treasure Yeti, it was already retreating off the screen, causing me to miss the chest.

What caused this behavior and what other things can the yeti zombie do?

Comment: I always bring a spikeweed into a yeti level. I plant it near my end of the map, and whey he starts to get away, I put a plant food on the spikeweed, which pulls all enemies in that row onto it, making his getaway much farther than he once anticipated!

Comment: that's a nice trick

Comment: Reccomend you put the wallnut behind the yeti zombies. Killed it five times by doing that

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128176/what-are-the-possible-drops-for-defeating-yeti-zombie

Comment: @user54218 - I've put a Wallnut behind the Yeti, and he's walked right by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just checked the [wiki](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie_Yeti), but it doesn't say anything about the time when will it run away. But it's one of his specialties, so you have to kill him ASAP. Quote from there:

> Zombie Yeti
>
> A rare and curious creature.
>
> Toughness: high
>
> Special: runs away after a short while
>
> Little is known about the Zombie Yeti other than his name, birth date,
>   social security number, educational history, past work experience, and
>   sandwich preference (roast beef and Swiss).

So it seems that running away is his normal behavior.

The wiki also provides a bit of strategy against them:

> Just do whatever you do to kill Buckethead Zombies (obviously besides
>   using Magnet-shrooms). If it tries to run away, it can be stopped by
>   planting a Wall-nut or another defensive plant in its path such as the
>   Pumpkin or Tall-nut.
>
> ...
>
> or an instant kill like Jalapeno, Squash or Cherry Bomb can be used.

It also says that it can take only 46 normal damage shots, so a *[Plant Food](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plant_Food)* planted on a *[Repeater](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Repeater)* should be enough to take him down I guess.

**EDIT**

Apparently there is also a *[Treasure Yeti](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Yeti)*, a new zombie in PvZ2. Probably it's the one that you encountered.

Not much is said about him, but:

> Toughness:     Dense
>
> Speed:     Basic
>
> Special:   Runs away after a short while, drops a lunchbox if killed

But comparing some other zombies(*[Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie)*, *[Conehead Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Conehead_Zombie)* and *[Buckethead Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Buckethead_Zombie)*) it looks like they still take the exact same amount of damage, so I'd assume that the Yeti will be as tough as in the first game(I've never seen him though).

**EDIT 2**

Yes, he runs away after some time and not distance. Just planted a walnut right in front of him and after a short while he flew away like a little scared girl.

Comment: so its not a distance thing that causes the runaway but time.  If I put a wallnut to the left of him he'll attack it for a while and retreat?

Comment: @spartacus I don't know it. I'll make another edit to the post after I encounter him. But if he starts to run away it's best to put a wallnut/tallnut to the right of him, so that it will stop him from running away

Answer (score 2):

Just get double sunflowers and keep some sun in the bank. As soon as he appears, plant a coconut cannon and blast him. I think that drops him completely or he only needs a couple more pea shots. I've killed two this way.

Answer (score -2):

Give him plant food on peashooter or repeater; I'm sure this will cause his head to fly away.